# Rotate components on image around a fixed point

Tags: image-processing, image

I have an binarized image

[image]

and a center

```
cvx = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QoEo.png";
center = {258.19137417775005`, 150.8459811782782`};
HighlightImage[cvx, center]
```

gives

[image]

I want to rotate this white triangle by 180 degree around this center point and keep the original image dimension.

If I run

```
rotCvx = 
 ImageTransformation[cvx, RotationTransform[\[Pi], center], 
  PlotRange -> All, Background -> White]
```

which gives

[image]

But this is not the correct rotated one. You can see from

```
ImageAdd[cvx, rotCvx]
```

gives

[image]

The correct one should give

[image]

So how to rotate components on image around a fixed point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this may be easy to overlook, but it's actually mentioned in **Details and Options** section of document of `ImageTransformation`:

> In 2D, the range of the coordinate system for the input image is assumed to be `{{0,1},{0,a}}`, where `a` is the aspect ratio. The bottom-left corner of the image corresponds to coordinates `{0,0}` by default.

> Other coordinate systems can be specified by setting the `DataRange` option.

> Typical settings for `DataRange` include: `Full`   - same ranges as the input image

So, you just need `DataRange -> Full`:

```
rotCvx = ImageTransformation[cvx, RotationTransform[π, center], 
  Background -> White, DataRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: I like it and accept it. Instantly solve the problem : )